# Use of global variable with ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Currently I am working on a website which uses asp.net and c#. I am getting data from the database using a `web service` and I get the correct data without an issue. However once I get the data via `ajax` call I need to assign it to a global variable which I later use to create a tree graph. This is where my problem comes, I've tried to assign the `JSON` object but I can't seem to get it to work. I keep getting an error

> TypeError: treeData is undefined

Can someone guide me please. Below is the relevant code

`Ajax Call`

```
$(function () {
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "MyService.asmx/SomeFunction",
   data: "{}",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: successHandler
   });
});
```

`SuccessHandler`

```
function successHandler(data) {
  var a = JSON.parse(data.d);
  var b = [JSON.stringify(a)];
}

var treeData = successHandler[0]; //This part keeps giving me error
```

Thanks in advance for all your help and support.

Comment: `successHandler` is a function not an array and don't forget AJAX is asynchronous

Comment: *"which I later use to create a tree graph"* - define *later*. e.g. if your network call takes 5 seconds to retrieve data over the wire, then how much later is *later*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access `successHandler` as an array, when it is a function. You cannot use it like that. Instead, assign the `[JSON.stringify(a)]` to a global variable, and access that variable when you need the data, like so:

```
var dataFromAjax; 
var treeData; 

function successHandler(data) {
    var a = JSON.parse(data.d);
    dataFromAjax = [JSON.stringify(a)];

    setTreeData();
}

function setTreeData() { //this function can be in the seperate script tag
    treeData = dataFromAjax[0]; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I get the following errors `TypeError: treeData is undefined` and `TypeError: dataFromAjax is undefined `

Comment: When are you trying to access treeData? If you're using it outside of the callback of the ajax call, treeData has probably not been set yet.

Comment: I'm accessing it in a separate `script` tag and then finally in another `js` file like `var root = treeData[0];`

Comment: Yeah, you can't do that. Then you have to wrap the other place in a function, so it doesn't get executed before the ajax request has finished. I will edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: It has now been edited in. Please remember that the place where you set `var root = treeData[0];` also cannot be executed before the ajax callback.

Comment: Right, I understand what you mean now.. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to return the object from the function and use it like this `successHandler()[0];`

```js
function successHandler(data) {
  var a = JSON.parse('[{"a":1, "b":2}]');
  return a; // you need to return the data from here.
}

var treeData = successHandler()[0]; //This part keeps giving me error
console.log(treeData)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, If I use `var treeData = successHandler()[0]; ` I get The following error `TypeError: data is undefined` and `console.log(treeData)` shows `undefined` too